# Is hive `INSERT OVERWRITE` atomic?

Tags: hive, apache-spark-sql

Is hive `INSERT OVERWRITE` atomic? I mean, will the data in hive be clean (either old or updated version, but not some nondeterministic state) if the hive client or server is down during `INSERT OVERWRITE`?
What if we make this operation by Spark SQL?

Comment: This should help: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions short answer-yes

Comment: Seems stronger guarantees are introduced in 0.13. How about the `INSERT OVERWRITE` in 0.12? I don't need ACID, just need to know if the partition is clean in case of system down.

Comment: Hive 0.12 was released 15 October, 2013, 6 years ago ! So many important fixes and improvements were done even in 0.13 version: https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?version=12324986&styleName=Text&projectId=12310843  Why do you need to dig 0.12 up? Let it rest in peace